# leave the door closed?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

Leave the door **closed**.

Is the word '' closed '' in this sentence an adverb or an adjective? Can you explain with similar examples?

Answer (score 1):

It is an adjective. It can't be an adverb as it isn't modifying any other verb. It describes the condition of the door (ie 'the door is closed').

Similar examples:

- Leave the door open (open describes the door)
- Make my tea hot (hot describes the tea)
- Comb your hair flat (flat describes the hair)

Comment: It was a very informative explanation thank you very much